# Hide tooltip when click event occur

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click

I have set an auto refresh for email inbox using JavaScript below:

```
setInterval(function () {
            document.getElementById("emailReload").click();
            }, 
        120000
);
```

but it also triggers a tooltip to appear which stays on the screen. To prevent that I tried to hide it on click event:

```
    setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementById("emailReload").click(function() {
            $('div[id="opentip-5"]').css("visibility","hidden");
        });
        }, 
    120000
    );
```

but this is not working as I have expected.

Tooltip HTML code looks like:

```
<div id="opentip-5" class="opentip-container style-standard ot-fixed ot-show-effect-fade ot-hide-effect-fade stem-center stem-top ot-visible" style="position: absolute; width: 151px; left: 147px; top: 48px; z-index: 105; transition-duration: 0.2s; visibility: visible;">
<canvas width="153" height="40" style="position: absolute; width: 153px; height: 40px; left: -1px; top: -6px;"></canvas>
<div class="opentip">
   <div class="ot-header"></div>
   <div class="ot-content">Reload Message List</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please provide a full code sample, such as a JSFiddle.

Comment: @Feathercrown this is a full code which I have added to a default Rainloop code

Comment: Ah. Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got is solved

```
setInterval(function () {
  document.getElementById("emailReload").click();
  document.getElementById("opentip-5").setAttribute('style','visibility: hidden');
  }, 
  12000
);
```

Looks like Rainloop do not user jQuery just pure JavaScript only.